# Remove quotes when using assign function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I'm trying to read in output from another program into R. The data I'm reading in comes in as a line with the variable name preceded by the # sign (e.g., #var1) followed by another line of the values, followed by a variable name, followed by values, etc. I'm trying to read the input file and parse out the variables with the values associated. Some variables are scalars, while others are vectors. The problem I'm running into is when I use the assign function it puts quotes around my variable names as well as the values. If the values are a vector then there are quotes surrounding the entire vector, not individual values. I have tried using the noquote function inside my for loop, but the output still has quotes. Any ideas how to remove these quotes within the looping structure?

thank you!

```
f <- scan(fname,what=character(),sep = "\n", quiet =TRUE,blank.lines.skip=F)
length(f)

varname_idx <- seq(1,length(f),2)
values_idx <- seq(2,length(f),2)

varname <- list()
values <- list()

for(i in 1:length(varname_idx)){
   varname[i]<-substr(f[[varname_idx[i]]],2,20)
   values[i]<- f[[values_idx[i]]]       

 assign(varname[[i]][1], values[[i]])  
}
```

Some additional info - f looks like this:

```
[1] "#var1"
[2] "0.3009"
[3] "#var2"
[4] "1 13 24 5 6 12"
...
```

Comment: if you're trying to read in data from an AD Model Builder output file, you might see if there's something in the `R2admb` package that could help you, e.g. `read_pars` or `read_rep` ...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to read ADMB output. Thank you for comment. I am trying read_pars(code.par, drop_phase=T), but that doesn't appear to be the correct syntax. Do you have additional info on what fn should be in this command? Thank you again!

Comment: I think it's looking for `read_pars("code",drop_phase=TRUE)` (i.e. the basename: not `"code.par"` but `"code"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are separated by spaces, you could split them by spaces, unlist and transform to numeric. Something like this should work (it works in your sample of the `f` data ):

```
for(i in 1:length(varname_idx)){
  varname[i]<-substr(f[[varname_idx[i]]],2,20)
  values[[i]]<- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(f[[values_idx[i]]], " ")))

  assign(varname[[i]][1], values[[i]])  
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I do in fact remove the # in the for loop by substr starting with the second character.

Comment: @Tiffany, you're right, so what do you mean by "it puts quotes around my variable names"? I have just tested here and the variables have been assigned properly.

Comment: I want to be able to call the variable name after the code is run. So for example, var1 would return 0.3009, but instead it returns "0.3009". I have used noquotes on the values in the loop, but when I call the variable names the return is always inside quotes.

Comment: @Tiffany if you run `values[[i]]<- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(f[[values_idx[i]]], " ")))` inside your loop it will work.

Comment: @Tiffany, you're welcome! Now, keep in mind that this may not be the most efficient way to do this. Perhaps you could use another function instead of `scan` that would already read your data in a nicer format.